# Want to refer to previous transactions in transaction processor function

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have 2 types of transaction :

- orderrequest ( provide details including orderer name and transaction id )
- ordereraccept (provide id of the orderrequest transaction being accepted)

within the transaction processor function of orderaccept i want to refer to the previous orderrequest transaction using the id to perform validation

i was thinking of using some form of historian but have not been able to get anything to work .

In the test section of composer playground i am able to view previous transactions so I just need a way to do this within a transaction processor function

Thanks a lot

Comment: not enough detail about exactly how much you want to retrieve  using a transaction id?  Can you also  post a model, some TP code of what you're trying to do? your `orderaccept` function can accept a parameter to find the (previously created) 'orderrequest' transaction by txn id but to resolve the detail you would probably use a loopback filter via REST API call - as described in https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--historian-queries---common-asks and a call-out eg https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I have solved my problem ! Would Upvote but can't seem to be able to for some reason.